# Created text controls dynamically in wxpython. How can i retrieve the data from them?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've created a wxframe with a button which when clicked brings up a child frame that generates text controls with data stored from a dictionary named "samples" as shown below. The idea of the child frame is that it is an edit window for editing the data.

My problem is I don't know how to retrieve data from the generated text controls. I can only get data from the last generated text control.

Here is a simplified version of the code I created:

```
import wx

class MyFrame1(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        self.frame=wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.f3 = wx.Frame(None,-1,'Edit Tags')

        self.editTag = wx.Button(self.panel_1, -1, "Edit Tags", size=(100, 50))
        self.editTag.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.editTags)

        self.Bind( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.CloseAll)



        # end wxGlade

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def editTags(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        samples={
              "Face1":"(100,100)", \
              "Face2":"(50,40)", \
              "Car":"(500,230)", \
              "Wallclock":"(120,230)"

            }

        self.f3.okButton = wx.Button(self.f3, label="OK")
        self.f3.okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOK)
        self.f3.okButton.SetPosition((40,200))

        spacer=0

        for k, v in sorted(samples.iteritems()):
            print "K: ", k

            spacer=spacer+40
            print "V: ", v
            print

        self.f3.new_TextControl = wx.TextCtrl(self.f3, -1, value=k)
        self.f3.new_TextControl.SetPosition((40,spacer))

        print

        self.f3.Show()

   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onOK(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
        print self.f3.new_TextControl.GetValue()
        print self.f3.new_TextControl.GetValue()
        print "OK clicked"
        self.f3.Hide()
   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def CloseAll(self, event):
        self.DestroyChildren()  # First destroy child frames
        self.Destroy()          # Then destroy the parent frame
        self.f3.Close()
        self.Close()
   #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # end of class MyFrame1
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
        frame_1 = MyFrame1(None, -1, "")
        app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
        frame_1.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Any alternative solutions are welcome as well

I'm using python 2.7.2. and wxpython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look through your code:

```
def editTags(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
    samples={
          "Face1":"(100,100)", \
          "Face2":"(50,40)", \
          "Car":"(500,230)", \
          "Wallclock":"(120,230)"

        }

    self.f3.okButton = wx.Button(self.f3, label="OK")
    self.f3.okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOK)
    self.f3.okButton.SetPosition((40,200))
```

Let's make a storage for your new controls (will discuss it below):

```
    self.f3.new_controls = {}

    spacer=0
```

Here you iterate over your future fields and here's a problem:

```
    for k, v in sorted(samples.iteritems()):
        print "K: ", k

        spacer=spacer+40
        print "V: ", v
        print
```

The next step: you actually create your controls. Here is where some issues hide:

1. You create it out of your cycle, you must put them inside for-loop block (in your variant only one text control (stored in `new_TextControl` field is created)), and it will be a field for the last iterated `v` value (that's how `for` works).
2. You need to create some container (remember `self.f3.new_controls` we created above?) to hold your controls (e.g. a `dict)`.

So let's make some further changes to your code:

```
        # Dict will hold {'Car': wx.TextCtrl(...), 'Wallclock': ...}
        self.f3.new_controls[k] = wx.TextCtrl(self.f3, -1, value=k)
        self.f3.new_controls[k].SetPosition((40,spacer))
```

And you show your frame, that's ok:

```
    self.f3.Show()
```

You can access values of newly created fields from `new_controls` dict:

```
self.f3.new_controls['Car'].GetValue()  # Receive input from 'Car' text control.
```

Comment: im getting a "NameError:global name 'new_controls'" is not defined
 when I put this code in the onOK method->>                                                               for k, v in sorted(new_controls.iteritems()):
            print self.new_controls[k].GetValue()

Comment: @user1401950 Are you pressing OK before pressing Edit? Move the `self.new_controls` definition into your regular init function. Really, anytime you plan to use a `self` variable you should initialize it in your init function, even if it means just setting it to an empty or default value.

Comment: @acattle no the OK button is in the child frame called f3 but I figured it out.

Comment: @Rostyslav Dzinko Thanks for your help, How do I delete all the widgets afterwards because the dictionary I use changes each time and the number of entries in that dictionary will then also obviously change?

Comment: You must call Destroy() on each of your widgets (hold in a dict) and then recreate a new dict with new items inside

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko please look at this ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168256/creating-subclass-for-wx-textctrl