# Creating subclass for wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm creating a subclass for the wx.TextCtrl in wxpython.

I want this class to add extra data to the wx.TextCtrl widgets similar as to the way extra data can be added to a ComboBox or ListBox.

Here's my code:

```
import wx
class ExtraDataForTxtCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):

    def __init(self, ExtraTextData):
        self.ExtraTextData=ExtraTextData


    def getExtraTCData(self):
        return self.ExtraTextData

    def setExtraTCData(self, ExtraTextData):
        self.ExtraTextData=ExtraTextData
```

My problem is that I'm new to python and have no idea how to implement this and if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
import wx
class ExtraDataForTxtCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.ExtraTextData=kwargs.pop("ExtraTextData")
        wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)


    def getExtraTCData(self):
        return self.ExtraTextData

    def setExtraTCData(self, ExtraTextData):
        self.ExtraTextData=ExtraTextData
```

possibly a better solution would be to use set/getattr

```
class DataTxtCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.datadict = {}
        self.ExtraTextData=kwargs.pop("ExtraTextData")
        wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return self.datadict[attr]
    def __setattr__(self,attr,val):
        self.datadict[attr]=val
```

then you can set many variables and use it like normal

```
   a = wx.App(redirect=False)
   f = wx.Dialog(None,-1,"Example")
   te = DataTxtCtrl(f,-1,"some_default")
   te.somevar = "hello"
   te.someother = "world"
   print te.somevar+" "+te.someothervar
   f.ShowModal()
```

Comment: For a beginner I would suggest, instead of `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, using `def __init__(self, parent, extraTextData)`. You lose some functionality (e.g. using my code you can't set the size unless you add a `size` argument) but it's easier to understand. Usually you can get away with just setting `parent` when `init`ing built-in wxPython classes and let the rest be the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the help how do I go about implementing it? Lets say the name of the class is subTextCtrl, do I import subTextCtrl and create a control as follows: new_control=subTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value="hello"))?

Comment: You would just instantiate the subclass:  myTxtCtrl = ExtraDataForTxtCtrl()

Comment: well Mike is simplifying a bit i think it would be `myTxtCtrl = ExraDataForTxtCtrl(somePanel,someId,"Some Text for default",ExtraTextData={'some':extra,'text':data})` ; then you would treat it just like a normal textctrl  ... btw welcome to wxPython its awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a subclass I just decided to create my own class which links an extra string value to wx.textCtrl widgets.

Thanks to all who contributed! :)

Heres my code:

```
class TextDataHolder:
    def __init__(self, wxTextControl, data):

        self.wxTextControl=wxTextControl
        self.data=data

    def setDataTxt(self,data):
        self.wxTextControl=wxTextControl
        self.data=data

    def getDataTxt(self):
        return self.data
```

Heres how I implemented it:

```
import wx, TextDataHolder

exampleCtrl=wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Hello")
exampleData=TextDataHolder.TextDataHolder(exampleCtrl,"Sup?")
print exampleData.getDataTxt() #prints 'Sup?'
```